# Select added listitem of select

Tags: jquery

I have a select:

```
    <select id="club">
      <option>&nbsp;</option>
      <option value=bla1>bla1</option>
      <option value=bla2>bla2</option>
    </select>
```

I added an item as first item to the `<select>` with this code, which works fine:

```
$("#club option").eq(0).before("<option value=1>test</option>").css("background-color", "#F2EE72");
```

But the empty option is still selected, and I want the just added item to be selected, so it's visible as default item in the listbox. How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you add the new option node before the `eq(0)`, you simply need to chain a `prev()` to access it.

Like this:

```
$("#club option").eq(0).before('<option value="1">test</option>').css("background-color", "#F2EE72").prev().prop('selected',true);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/9EVjn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1)

```
$("#club option").eq(0).before("<option selected value=1>test</option>").css("background-color", "#F2EE72");
```

or

2)

```
 $("#club option").eq(0).before("<option value=1>test</option>").css("background-color", "#F2EE72");
 $("#club").val(1);
```